# Given a $2\times 2$ invertible matrix $A$ with real entries, does $L_A$ map open set to open set?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

For any $2\times 2$ matrix $A$, let $L_A: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by $L_A(z) = Az$.

> Question: Given an $2\times 2$ **invertible** matrix $A$ with real entries, does $L_A$ map open set to open set?

I think it is true but do not know how to approach this problem.
Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since all linear map $L:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ is continuous, obviously, if $A$ is invertible, then it's open. Indeed, the converse of a linear map $\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ is also linear map $\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$, and thus continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is true. All you need that for any matrix $A$, $L_A$ is continuous and that $L_A$ is invertible with $L_A^{-1}=L_{A^{-1}}$. Then use that for continuous maps, the pre-image of open maps is open. Now consider that the image of an open set $U$ under $L_A$ is just the pre-image of $U$ under $L_A^{-1}=L_{A^{-1}}$. So as a pre-image of an open set under the continuous map $L_{A^{-1}}$, the image of $U$ is open.